# IDEA cannot package the project that includes the custom jar file into the war package?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, package

I have a custom jar file that includes some util packages I want to use. When I put the jar file in my SpringBoot 2.0 project, it works very good(no errors and these util classes work normally). But when I package the project(SpringBoot project that includes the custom jar file) into the war package, the IDEA hinted the error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGwOA.png)

The project structure of my SpringBoot project is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PbX5.png)

And:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL4DY.png)

I don't know what is wrong, please help me, thank you very much! :)

Comment: It would be better to give your screens shots as examples in the question. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Okay, I will notice it in the future, thanks. :)

Comment: @user10833508 see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html. resources directory is the wrong location for the jars. If the project is Maven/Gradle based, you should modify pom.xml/build.gradle files instead to include additional dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The second image has some problem, here is the correct one:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysfjF.png)